# how to do a hexadecimal increment?

Tags: python

I have the following code which increments the value in `\\network\loc\build_ver.txt` by value "1". The issue currently is that it does an integer increment, but I want to do a hexadecimal increment because the input is going to be a hexadecimal value.

I've tried this:

```
with open(r'\\network\loc\build_ver.txt','r+') as f:
    value = int(f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(str(value + 1))
```

Comment: Show us the exact value inside build_ver.txt.

Comment: FYI the decimal value `1` is equal to the hex value `0x01`. For example to say `15 + 1 = 16`, that is identical to `0x0f + 0x01 = 0x10`. So you can increment literally any base by adding 1.

Comment: "Hexadecimal" and "integer" are not mutually exclusive. Hexadecimal is one way of _displaying_ an integer; decimal is another; Roman numerals are a third.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`int` builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) has an optional `base` parameter, which you can use to read hex values.

```
with open(r'\\network\loc\build_ver.txt','r+') as f:
    value = int(f.read(), 16)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(hex(value + 1))
```

You can use [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) for base 16 output or `str` for base 10 output.

```
>>> val = int("9a", base=16)
>>> val
154
>>> hex(val + 1)
'0x9b'
>>> str(val + 1)
'155'
```

It's also worth noting that you should either validate the input or have a `try` block somewhere:

```
>>> int("g", 16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'g'
```

Answer (score 7):

Hex is in Python is stored in the form of strings.  Incrementing is done on integers.  So you just need to convert to an integer and back:

```
>>> h = '0x3f8'        # hex string
>>> i = int(h, 16)     # convert to an integer
>>> i += 1             # increment
>>> hex(i)             # convert back to hex string
'0x3f9'
```

Hope this solves your problem neatly :-)

Comment: It certainly should :) Thus, OP can use `value = int(f.read(), 16)` and `f.write(hex(value + 1))` in place of the 2nd and 4th lines shown.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Raymond's answer, I created a `for loop`

```
varhex = "0x000FFF" # starting hex value
for i in range(0, 10):      # how many times you want to increment
    i = int(varhex, 16)     # define i as the decimal equivalent of varhex
    i +=1                   # increment i by one
    print (hex(i))          # print out the incremented value, but in hex form
    varhex = hex(i)         # increment varhex by 1
```

and when I run, the resulting list is:

```
0x1000
0x1001
0x1002
0x1003
0x1004
0x1005
0x1006
0x1007
0x1008
0x1009
```

To run this code visit: https://repl.it/BmG9/1